# why CUDA doesn't result in speedup in C++ code?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I'm using VS2019 and have an NVIDIA GeForce GPU. I tried the code from this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/writing-lightning-fast-code-with-cuda-c18677dcdd5f

The author of that post claims to get a speedup when using CUDA. However, for me, the serial version takes around 7 milliseconds while the CUDA version takes around 28 milliseconds. Why is CUDA slower for this code? The code I used is below:

```
__global__
void add(int n, float* x, float* y)
{

    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
        y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}

void addSerial(int n, float* x, float* y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}

int main()
{
    int NSerial = 1 << 20;   
    float* xSerial = new float[NSerial];
    float* ySerial = new float[NSerial];
    for (int i = 0; i < NSerial; i++) {
        xSerial[i] = 1.0f;
        ySerial[i] = 2.0f;
    }
    auto t1Serial = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    addSerial(NSerial, xSerial, ySerial);
    auto t2Serial = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    auto durationSerial = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2Serial - t1Serial).count(); 
    float maxErrorSerial = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < NSerial; i++)
        maxErrorSerial = fmax(maxErrorSerial, fabs(ySerial[i] - 3.0f));
    std::cout << "Max error Serial: " << maxErrorSerial << std::endl;
    std::cout << "durationSerial: "<<durationSerial << std::endl;
    delete[] xSerial;
    delete[] ySerial;


    int N = 1 << 20;   

    float* x, * y;
    cudaMallocManaged(&x, N * sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&y, N * sizeof(float));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        x[i] = 1.0f;
        y[i] = 2.0f;
    }


    int device = -1;
    cudaGetDevice(&device);
    cudaMemPrefetchAsync(x, N * sizeof(float), device, NULL);
    cudaMemPrefetchAsync(y, N * sizeof(float), device, NULL);


    int blockSize = 1024;
    int numBlocks = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    add << <numBlocks, blockSize >> > (N, x, y);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count(); 

    float maxError = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i] - 3.0f));
    std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;
    std::cout << "duration CUDA: "<<duration; 

    cudaFree(x);
    cudaFree(y);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 7 ms is probably just too little too see any effect. try to increase the workload

Comment: when I change `NSerial = N = 1<<30`, then the serial version only takes 4seconds whereas CUDA takes 19sec

Comment: It is probably that moving memory around from RAM to GPU takes longer than making simple calculations on CPU. It depends on hardware.

Comment: Run the kernel ~100 times in a loop and take the average. Your synchronize call is will also affect performance.

Comment: Your memory access pattern is also seriously wrong. You're thrashing the cache like crazy.

Comment: @3Dave: I don't see anything to support that assertion. I see a simple grid size strided loop, which is the canonical way to achieve full memory coalescing with resident threads in CUDA.

Comment: The canonical answer to questions like this appears to be "try running code built in release mode, not debug".

Comment: I'm running it in release mode now and the CUDA version takes around 400 microseconds (when I run the kernel 10 times in a loop and take the average), and the serial around 780 microseconds. When I tried the code from @talonmies, the serial takes 780us and the second and subsequent CUDA runs take around 350us, so only around a 2x speedup

Answer (score 1):

There are several observations to make here:

1. The first call of a CUDA kernel can accumulate a lot of one time latency associated with setup on the GPU, so the normal approach is to include a "warm-up" call
2. The kernel design in your question is a "resident" design, so optimal execution should occur when you launch only as many blocks as required to fully occupy your GPU. There is an API you can use to get this information for your GPU.
3. Perform timing in microseconds, not milliseconds
4. Build your code in release mode.

Doing all of this to your CUDA code gets me this:

```
    int N = 1 << 20;   
    int device = -1;
    cudaGetDevice(&device);

    float* x, * y;
    cudaMallocManaged(&x, N * sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&y, N * sizeof(float));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        x[i] = 1.0f;
        y[i] = 2.0f;
    }
    cudaMemPrefetchAsync(x, N * sizeof(float), device, NULL);
    cudaMemPrefetchAsync(y, N * sizeof(float), device, NULL);

    int blockSize, numBlocks;
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&numBlocks, &blockSize, add);

    for(int rep=0; rep<10; rep++) {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        add << <numBlocks, blockSize >> > (N, x, y);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count(); 
        std::cout << rep << " duration CUDA: " << duration <<std::endl; 
    }

    float maxError = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i] - 12.0f));
    std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;

    cudaFree(x);
    cudaFree(y);
```

And building it and running it:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -std=c++11 -o not_so_fast not_so_fast.cu 
$ ./not_so_fast 
Max error Serial: 0
durationSerial: 2762
0 duration CUDA: 1074
1 duration CUDA: 150
2 duration CUDA: 151
3 duration CUDA: 158
4 duration CUDA: 152
5 duration CUDA: 152
6 duration CUDA: 147
7 duration CUDA: 124
8 duration CUDA: 112
9 duration CUDA: 113
Max error: 0
```

On my system, the first GPU run close to three times as fast as the serial loop. The second and subsequent runs are almost 10 times faster again. Your results can (and probably will) vary.

Comment: when I tried that in VS2019, the serial takes 780us and the second and subsequent CUDA runs take around 350us, so only around a 2x speedup

Comment: Like I said, your results might vary