# Error when accessing CUDA array from cudaMalloc

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I'm using VS2019 and have an NVIDIA GeForce GPU. I tried the code from this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/writing-lightning-fast-code-with-cuda-c18677dcdd5f

However, I want to try using `cudaMalloc` instead of using managed memory with `cudaMallocManaged`

I tried the code below:

```
__global__
void add(int n, float* x, float* y)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
        y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}


int main()
{
    int N = 1 << 20;   

    float* x, * y;
    cudaMalloc(&x, N * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&y, N * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemset(x,1.0, N * sizeof(float)); //want to set x as an array of 1.0s
    cudaMemset(y,2.0, N * sizeof(float)); //want to set y as an array of 2.0s

    int device = -1;
    cudaGetDevice(&device);

    int blockSize = 1024;
    int numBlocks = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    add << <numBlocks, blockSize >> > (N, x, y);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count(); 

    float maxError = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i] - 3.0f));
    std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;
    std::cout << "duration CUDA: "<<duration; 

    cudaFree(x);
    cudaFree(y);

    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting an unhandled exception error at `maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i] - 3.0f));`, I'm guessing because I didn't use `cudaMemset` correctly? How should I modify it?

Comment: You can't substitute device memory for managed memory on the host, and you can't use cudaMemset to set floats

Comment: so what am I supposed to do instead then?

Comment: You can't access device memory on the host. You must explicitly copy to a host variable after the kernel,  and you should probably initialize host memory and copy to the device. And maybe read some API documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In no particular order:

1. Device memory (i.e.  memory allocated with `cudaMalloc`) can't be accessed directly on the host, so your `maxError` calculations are illegal because `y` is a pointer in device memory. To perform the error check, you require a copy of `y` to a local host copy of the memory before running the loop
2. `cudaMemset` [sets bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13387101/681865), not words (just like regular `memset`). You either need to set values on the host and copy them to the device, or in another kernel, or use something like [`thrust::fill_n`](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__filling_gaba85984f8afa1842e59589f2f58abae6.html#gaba85984f8afa1842e59589f2f58abae6).
3. In the spirit of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60085669/681865), there is typically setup latency in the first call of a kernel, so perform a warm-up before timing

Doing these three things gets me this:

```
int main()
{
    int N = 1 << 20;   

    std::vector<float> xh(N, 1.0f);
    std::vector<float> yh(N, 2.0f);

    float* x, * y;
    cudaMalloc(&x, N * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(x, &xh[0], N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc(&y, N * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(y, &yh[0], N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int blockSize, numBlocks;
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&numBlocks, &blockSize, add);

    for(int rep=0; rep<10; rep++) {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        add << <numBlocks, blockSize >> > (N, x, y);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count(); 
        std::cout << rep << " duration CUDA: " << duration <<std::endl; 
    }

    cudaMemcpy(&yh[0], y, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    float maxError = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(yh[i] - 12.0f));
    std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;

    cudaFree(x);
    cudaFree(y);

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

And compiling it and running it gets me this:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -std=c++11 -o devmem devmem.cu
$ ./devmem 
0 duration CUDA: 155
1 duration CUDA: 94
2 duration CUDA: 95
3 duration CUDA: 94
4 duration CUDA: 94
5 duration CUDA: 93
6 duration CUDA: 93
7 duration CUDA: 99
8 duration CUDA: 92
9 duration CUDA: 93
Max error: 0
```

Compared to the [timings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60093143/681865) in my last answer to you, you can see that using device memory provides speedup over managed memory on my system. As always, your results might vary.